# Connect to respective card in Hyperledger UI application

Tags: angularjs, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm new to hyperledger. Can you guys please tell.me how to connect to card while logged in via gmail to the application
UI interface consists of of some basic transactions to do.

To make that transaction by using the card only.

For example
If an application logged in with

```
a. Abc@gmail.com (has abc@mynetwork) card
b. Def@gmail.com (has def@mynetwork) card
```

Each transaction should use the particular card on the basis of gmail account used for logged in.

Application is running on port 4200 and composer rest server on 3000.

Its easy while doing the transaction using playground because there is an option to switch the cards but whereas in UI application how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using Gmail authentication to authenticate to the composer rest server. in that case, when you do login with your Gmail credentials, you will have an access token that you can correlate with the card by calling the "import" rest server API, providing the token and the card. After this you will not need the card any more, the access token can be used alone to authenticate the calls to the rest server.
So, in your case, Abc@gmail.com will have an access token and Def@gmail.com will have another access token. 
to switch between accounts you just need to use the correct access token when calling the API.